# Signoz postgres database tracing with open telemetry

Tags: postgresql, open-telemetry, signoz

Im using self hosted version of signoz and i've tried adding

```
    endpoint: <POSTGRESQL_URL>:<POSTGRESQL_PORT>
    username: <POSTGRESQL_USERNAME>
    password: <POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD>
  postgresql/all:
    endpoint: <POSTGRESQL_URL>:<POSTGRESQL_PORT>
    transport: tcp
        username: <POSTGRESQL_USERNAME>
    password: <POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD>
    databases:
      - <YOUR DATABASE 1>
      - <YOUR DATABASE 2>
            # ... All databases you want to monitor
    collection_interval: 10s
    tls:
      insecure: true
      insecure_skip_verify: true
```

in otel-collector-config.yaml but it didn't help. I still have empty dashboard. I restarted docker container with the collector after i updated config. What am i doing wrong.

Comment: What's the use case you are trying to solve? Do you want to measure postgres server metrics? Or things like how much time a request is spending in PostGres

Comment: @pranay01 Yes i want to see postgres server metrics (like db size, table size, etc) I imported the default postgres dashboard from signoz repo https://github.com/SigNoz/dashboards/blob/main/postgresql/postgresql.json and this dashboard is empty

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add Postgresql to the metrics pipelines section.
Eg:

```
service:
  telemetry:
    metrics:
      address: localhost:8888
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [postgresql, postgresql/all]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [otlp]
```

Reference to visualization for this config: https://www.otelbin.io/s/180fda380204bfa1f1891415c50bfe0323efbb01

Comment: I updated the pipelines section and still there is no data
I waited for 10 min in hope that it will appear

This is my current config
https://www.otelbin.io/s/1013ce74508abb2ff15c4e44482fca5014423e0d

Comment: @danyalutsevich Can you please ask the question in SigNoz Slack Community?
https://signoz.io/slack

Comment: yes ofc, thank yo