# Signoz postgres tracing

Tags: postgresql, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector, signoz

This question is the duplicate of [Signoz postgres database tracing with open telemetry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77826901/signoz-postgres-database-tracing-with-open-telemetry)

there is no tag feachure on stackoverflow so i made it this way
sorry for spam

Im using self hosted version of signoz and i've tried adding

```
  endpoint: <POSTGRESQL_URL>:<POSTGRESQL_PORT>
  username: <POSTGRESQL_USERNAME>
  password: <POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD>
postgresql/all:
  endpoint: <POSTGRESQL_URL>:<POSTGRESQL_PORT>
  transport: tcp
      username: <POSTGRESQL_USERNAME>
  password: <POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD>
  databases:
    - <YOUR DATABASE 1>
    - <YOUR DATABASE 2>
          # ... All databases you want to monitor
  collection_interval: 10s
  tls:
    insecure: true
    insecure_skip_verify: true
```

also i've added revcievers but it didnt help

```
  telemetry:
    metrics:
      address: localhost:8888
  pipelines:
    metrics:
      receivers: [postgresql, postgresql/all]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [otlp]
```

in otel-collector-config.yaml but it didn't help. I still have empty dashboard. I restarted docker container with the collector after i updated config. What am i doing wrong.

PS. thanks for answering my previous question, but I think I need a little more help from you

[image]